# flag for overly broad

Tags: discussion

Following up this discussion [LMGTFY questions abound?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/lmgtfy-questions-abound). [3000 points](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) are required to vote to close a question and that most users will never have 3000 points. I found a flag for overly specific questions is there be a flag for overly general questions or questions which show no research on behalf of the asker? If this is already a feature where do I flag for too general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available flags roughly correspond the the choices we have when closing a question. The sort of question you are referring to sometimes falls under either "Not Constructive" or "Not a real question". We don't actually have a close reason for "Too Basic" which is what the LMGTFY thing is about, but usually when people try questions of this sort there is also another issue going on that we can deal with.

If you think a question really ought to be closed, go and flag with the best match you can think of. Whoever acts on the flag will still have to make a judgement call and pick the close reason themselves. The flag type doesn't actually determine the close type even if a moderator agrees.

In the mean time, 3,000k rep isn't actually that high of a bar. It's a big step up from beta, but it's a standard across other graduated SE sites that works pretty well as a threshold for new users to really get a feel for things. I hope to see a lot of regulars pushing through and being active close/reopen voters.

Comment: thanks for pointing those two options out :)

Comment: IMO "Extremely low quality" seems appropriate for those as well.